# jQuery: split string and append html to split element

Tags: jquery, html, css

There are multiple event date div.

HTML:

```
 <div class="event-dates">Aug 28</div>
 <div class="event-dates">Aug 28</div>
 <div class="event-dates">Aug 28</div>
 <div class="event-dates">Aug 28</div>
```

JQuery:

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery(".event-dates").each(function() {
           jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().replace(/ /g, '<br />'));
      });

 });
```

I want output like first attached image.is it possible to split string and append with html?

OR

Any other way to get such a output?

Expected result as shown in first image

[image]      [image: output needed]

Comment: it looks like some css problem http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8Vx3V/1/

Comment: got output like attched image with your code but i want to add html code to it.<span class="firest">Aug</sapn><span class="day">25</span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do what you want:

JS

```
jQuery.noConflict();    
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".event-dates").html(function(index, oldHtml) {
        var split = oldHtml.split(' ');
        return '<div class="month">' + split[0] + '</div><div class="day">' + split[1] + '</div>';
    });    
});
```

CSS

```
div.event-dates {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
}

div.month {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}

div.day {
    width: 50px;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/ex8x7/

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".event-dates").html(function(idx, html) {
        return html.replace(/([a-z]+)\s(\d+)/i, '<span class="firest">$1</sapn><span class="day">$2</span>')
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8Vx3V/)

Comment: That's pretty cool, can you explain how the Regex works with $1 and $2?

Comment: those are used to refer to the groups specified in the regex expression